# Matching And Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Prove that if $G=(A \cup B,E)$ is bipartite and $|A|=n$ and $|B|=n$, $|E|>kn$ , then $G$ contains a matching of size $k+1$

I don't ask for a solution but rather idea how to approach the problem.
Another unrelated question is : I am having troubles with graph theory , I know all the theorems and lemmas , but when it comes to questions from exams I feel hopless, do you have a tip for me on how to get better at solving questions from graph theory? Or a helpfull trick on how to approach questions from graph theory?

Comment: As with most areas in Mathematics, there's hardly a general trick that will help you approach questions in Graph Theory. Getting better at Graph Theory means not just knowing the theorems, but understanding why they are true and where and how they can be applied. This usually comes with time and exercises: in fact, try not just to solve the exercise, but to understand what method you apply and in what other situations it can also be applied.

Comment: @PedroM. I know , I understand the idead (or so I think) , but I never had this kind of feeling that no method that I saw can be helpfull (every question that I understand the solution to , looks to me like a new technique and idea I never saw).

Comment: I don't know how to close the question , I found a solution:
Using induction on $k$, and the fact that there has to be a vertex of degree at least $2k+1$ we can find a vertex that was not in the previous matching , and add the edge connecting both of them to the matching.

Comment: You can also answer your own question. This is perfectly acceptable, as others may profit from your question and solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a quick fix or a silver bullet to solve any exam. If there were we all would do it. The practical thing that works for me at getting better is to rewrite a proof I read in my own structure. This makes a real difference for me: by just reading a proof I often overlook a detail or underestimate a solution technique or just accept a "fact" that actually needs clarification. A nice side effect is that I find more errors or left-outs than by just reading. It takes a lot of time but I get much deeper under the skin of things by actual writing it up with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am a stickler for details, I have the following proposal for a solution.

Let $G = (V,E) = (A\cup  B,E)$ be a (simple) balanced bipartite graph with $|V| = 2 \cdot n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.
If $|E| > k \cdot n$ for $0 \leq k < n$, then $G$ contains a matching of size $k+1$.

We assume $n>1$ (otherwise the claim is evident) and use induction on $k$ (for graphs of the described kind).

Denote $E(U,W) := \{u w \in E:: u \in U\setminus W \wedge w \in W\setminus U\}$ for $U,W \subseteq V$ as the set of edges between vertex sets $U$ and $W$ in $G$.
We use $d(v)$ for $v \in V$ to denote the number of edges in $G$ incident with $v$.
Finally, $N(v) = \{w \in V:: v w \in E\}$ are the neighbours of $v$ in $G$.

Case 0 ($k = 0$): Since $G$ contains at least one edge, it follows that it contains a matching of size $1 = 0 + 1$.

Case 1 ($k = 1$): Then, $G$ contains a least $3$ edges.
Suppose all edges are adjacent. Choose any edge $xy \in E$.
If there are distinct edges $e_1,e_2 \in E\setminus \{xy\}$ incident with $x$ and $y$, respectively, then they are disjoint because $G$ is bipartite, 
that is, it contains no odd cycles (if $e_1$ and $e_2$ were adjacent via another vertex $z \in V\setminus \{x,y\}$, then $x y z x$ is a triangle).
This is a contradiction to the supposition. 
So, $G$ contains at least $2$ disjoint edges, i.e., a matching of size $2 = 1 + 1$.

Case 2 ($k > 1$): We know that $G$ contains a matching $M \subseteq E$ of size $k = (k-1)+1$ by induction hypothesis because $|E|>k\cdot n > (k-1)\cdot n$.

Let $A' \subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$ be the set of (by $M$) matched vertices in $G$.
We see $|A'| = k = |B'|$.
Since $k<n$, there are $n-k$ unmatched vertices left in $A'' := A\setminus A'$ and $B'' := B\setminus B'$, i.e., $|A''| = n-k = |B''|$.

If there is an edge $a'' b'' \in E$ with $a'' \in A''$ and $b'' \in B''$, then we can augment the matching $M$ to $M \cup \{a'' b''\}$ of size $k+1$.
So, assume that $E(A'',B'') = \emptyset$.

Let $a b \in M$ be an edge with $a \in A'$ and $b \in B'$. 
If we can find vertices $a' \in A''$ and $b' \in B''$ with $a b', a' b \in E$,
then we can change the matching $M$ to a matching $(M\setminus \{ab\}) \cup \{a b', a' b\}$ of size $k+1$.
So, assume this is impossible, 
i.e., $\forall ab \in M: (N(a) \subseteq B' \vee N(b) \subseteq A') \wedge d(a) + d(b) \leq n + k < 2 \cdot n$.

Case 2.1 ($\forall a b \in M: d(a) + d(b) = n + k$): Then, $\{d(a), d(b)\} = \{n,k\}$.
It follows $G[A' \cup B'] = K_{k,k}$, that is, the vertices of $A'$ and $B'$ form a complete bipartite subgraph in $G$.
Therefore, if there is a vertex $a_0 \in A'$ with $d(a_0) = n$, then $\forall a \in A': d(a) = n$ and $\forall b \in B': d(b) = k$.
By symmetry of argument this holds analogously for any $b_0 \in B'$ with $d(b_0) = n$.
Without loss of generality we assume a vertex $a_0 \in A'$ with $d(a_0) = n$.

Moreover, from $E(A'',B'') = \emptyset$ and $\forall a \in A': d(a) = n$ follows $\forall b \in B: d(b) = k$ 
and so $k \cdot n < |E| = \sum_{b \in B} d(b) = n \cdot k$ which is a contradiction.

Case 2.2 ($\exists a_1 b_1 \in M: d(a_1) + d(b_1) \leq n + k - 1$): Define $H := G - \{a_1, b_1\} = (V',E')$ with $|V'|=2 \cdot (n-1)$.
Then, $|E|-(n+k-1) \leq |E'|$ and so $(k-1)\cdot (n-1) = k \cdot (n-1+1)-(n-1+k) = k \cdot n - (n+k-1) < |E'|$.

It follows that $H$ has a matching $M' \subseteq E(H)\subsetneq E(G)$ of size $k$ by induction hypothesis. 
We augment $M'$ to $M' \cup \{a_1 b_1\}$ as a matching of $G$ of size $k+1$.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution if had $n$ vertices : Using induction on k, and the fact that there has to be a vertex of degree at least 2k+1 we can find a vertex that was not in the previous matching , and add the edge connecting both of them to the matching (we need also need to use the fact that removing any vertex still preserves the property of having more than $(k-1)$(n-1) edges)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a solution but a question: If I choose a star for $G$ with $6$ vertices (i.e., one as the centre of the star and $5$ satellite vertices), then $G$ is bipartite with $|V(G)| = 2 \cdot 3$ and $|E(G)| = 5 > 1 \cdot 3 = 3$. But every star contains a matching of at most one edge and not $k+1 = 2$ in this case. Do you think you have the correct theorem?

Comment: The theorem was correct, I thought that it was obvious in the context that bot sides are of equal sizes , I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! So, my counter-example is none after all.

Answer (score 0):

In our case simple induction on $n$ adn $k$ would work , you justneed to observe that if thre is a matching of size $k$ , then we must have two vertices that are matced and the sum of there degree is not more than $n+k-1$